# Jquery json

Tags: jquery, json, php

Есть код который должен передавать и получать ответ от сервера.

```
$.getJSON("/index.php?r=site/update&id=<?php echo $model->primaryKey; ?>", {i:i},
                 function(data) {
                    alert('Сервер ответил: '+data); 
                    em = data.rez; 
                    alert(em);
                });
```

Передача может и проходит а в data ничего нет. Вот код на php: функцыя

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
        $rez = array();
        $model_contact = Contact::model()-  >findAll(array('condition'=>'id='.$id));
        foreach ($model_contact as $val){
            if($val->type == 'email'){
                //$rez = $val->value; 
                array_push($rez, $val->value);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode(array("data" => $rez[$i]));
```

Comment: во первых - data.data а не data.rez

во вторых - что такое `$i` ?

Comment: ..... function(data){ console.log(data); ...... посмотрите что приходит, чтобы в вопросе убрать "может". И согласен с eicto, откуда взялась $i ?

Comment: i это переменная обявленая выше. Допустим щас она i = 5;

Comment: покажите, что в консоле выводится при console.log(data)

Comment: Так то console.log(); работает. А в функцыи function(data){console.log(data);} не пашет. И alert не выводится значит функцыя почемуто не срабатывает.

Comment: А вы уверены, что у Вас вообще getJSON вызывается?

Comment: GET http://site.test.com/index.php?r=home/update&id=2004&i=1
GET http://site.test.com/index.php?r=home/update&id=2004&i=2
Показывает что отправляет 9-ть таких запросов. Цыфры идут на сервер а назад поче му то не могу получить результат.

Comment: Если уходят, а назад ничего нету, то: 1) в PHP не доходит до кода формирования JSON, 2) какая-то ошибка в коде, и стоит запрет на вывод ошибок, поэтому ничего не возвращается. Удостоверьтесь сначала что нет ошибок, т.е. причину 2, и если с синтаксисом все в порядке ищите причину 1. Может роутер не корректно настроен. Я так понимаю это Yii. Попробуйте прям в строке браузера передать данные и посмотрите выполнится ли ваш PHP код

Comment: Спасиба aldem67. Всьо работает. 
Может скажете, можна ли ускорить процесс запросов. Потому что у меня некоторые доп. поля заполняются через этот запрос. Да еще и добавляются динамически при посткплении ответа. Может это нада как то не так всьо делать.?